# Identity (logarithms)

Tags: logarithms

There is a simple question for identity:

$\log_{ab}X = \frac{\log(a)X \times \log(b)X}{\log(a)X + \log(b)X}$

To proof, I goes for $ab$ base for right, but seems Im wrong.

Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you mean $\frac{\log_{a}X\times\log_{b}X}{\log_{a}X+\log_{b}X}$?

Comment: yes! Solved! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$\log_r s=\frac1{\log_s r}$$